# Axios - catch() possibility to pass props?

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am trying to setState for loading after a response error has been catched by the axios .catch() function, but so far, it only allows the error props itself. Is there a way to pass the state props so I can setState after an error has been catched?

```
this.setState({loading: true})
axios.get(`${wordpressUrl}/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/727?password=${password}`)
.then(res => {
  this.setState({
    data: res.data,
    loading: false,
    visible: true
  })
})
.catch((error) => {
  if (error.response) {
    alert("Invalid password.");
    this.setState({ loading: false });
    this.forceUpdate();
    console.log(error.response.data);
    console.log(error.response.status);
    console.log(error.response.headers);
  }
});
```

Code example is what I would ideally want to achieve.

EDIT: 1
I tried the following, but the .then function just skips the response.status else and continues to catch() the error:

```
.then(response => {
  if(response.status === 403) {
    alert("Invalid password.");
    this.setState({ loading: false });
    this.forceUpdate();
  } else {
    this.setState({
      data: response.data,
      loading: false,
      visible: true
    })
  }
})
.catch(error => {
  if (error.response) {
    console.log(error.response.data);
    console.log(error.response.status);
    console.log(error.response.headers);
  }
});
```

I AM NOT GONNA SET THIS AS AN ANSWER, SO I'LL EDIT MY QUESTION:
It wasn't clear enough for me how to pass any props to the catch to so on make a detailed and user friendly catching method.
So I did the following:

```
.catch(error => {
  this.setState({loading: false})
  console.clear()
  console.log(error);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send a variable to the catch block you can use `throw` inside of one of the then block. You can use `throw` like a `return` statement.

`throw myProps`.

You will then get `myProps` as the argument you declared for the catch block.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not sure by what you mean? How would I implement this exactly?

Comment: you can do something like if (response.status === 403) throw response, so now the error variable in your catch block contains response

Comment: ah, you responded. Yes, I've tried that as well. If the response is a 403, it just skips over the .then and goes to the .catch. So I can put an if (response.status === 403), but it never gets there.